# Keyboard shortcut for in-application action (Spotify play/pause) from another application

Tags: macos, shortcut, script, customization, spotify

Is there a way to write a script, get an app, automator, or etc that would make spotify play/pause with a keyboard shortcut such as `cmd`+`alt`+`shift`+`p` that would work from outside of Spotify?

In other words, this shortcut would function like the function media key `f8` (play/pause), except it would be specific to Spotify only.